# Combining two filters

Tags: reactjs, typescript, lodash

I am trying to perform two filters at once, however my implementation just returns the entire list instead of filtering, I assume it is because of the OR operator but I'm not sure why this would occur.

```
examBank = this.props.toggleExamBankState.tests.filter(
      (tests: ITest) =>
        tests.companyPN.includes("25000") ||
        this.props.toggleExamBankState.question.filter((questions: IQuestion) =>
          questions.companyPN.includes("250001)
        )
    );

    console.log(examBank);
```

This is the data I am trying to filter.

```
Questions: [
  {
      companyPN: "250000"   
  },
  {
      companyPN: "250003"   
  },
  {
      companyPN: "251001"   
  }
]


Tests: [
  {
      companyPN: "250001"   
  },
  {
      companyPN: "250002"   
  },
  {
      companyPN: "251001"   
  }
]
```

My expected behaviour based on my filter should return

```
[
      {
          companyPN: "250000"   
      },
      {
          companyPN: "250001"   
      }
]
```

But instead returns both Questions and Test list.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? give expected output

Comment: Can you give a sample of the data you are trying to filter and a short explanation of how you're trying to filter it? Include the expected result, if possible. It's hard to see what the intention or what the data is here.

Comment: @DhananjaiPai I updated the question

Comment: @WishIWasSmart check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to filter one using another but I think you need to apply the filters separately. The reason your code returns the full array, that too only the tests array is because your nested filter will at least return and empty array `[]` and when that is compared with an `||` operator you will always be returned something.

I don't know the exact scenario you are going after but if you want to club `ITest` and `IQuestion` entries (not advisable though) into one single array then this will work using Array destructuring.

I removed the includes as it didn't look like you might need it, you can add it if you are comparing partial strings.

```
examBank = [
  ...this.props.toggleExamBankState.tests.filter(
      (test: ITest) => test.companyPN === <value>
    ),
  ...this.props.toggleExamBankState.question.filter(
      (question: IQuestion) => questions.companyPN === <value>
    )
]
```

```js
const Questions = [
  { companyPN: "250000" },
  { companyPN: "250003" },
  { companyPN: "251001" }
]


const Tests = [
  { companyPN: "250001" },
  { companyPN: "250002" },
  { companyPN: "251001" }
]

const examBank = [
  ...Tests.filter(
      (test) => test.companyPN === "250001"
    ),
  ...Questions.filter(
      (question) => question.companyPN === "250000"
    )
]

console.log(examBank)
```

Comment: It works but you said not advisable could you elaborate? i am trying to create a live search. So after being filtered, the user can click on the filtered item.

Comment: I mean you are using Typescript and trying to mix ITest type and IQuestion type entries into one array, like two different types into one collection. Of course it depends on your business logic etc. but usually better to separate concerns I think.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, I assume you want to create a examBank from 2 arrays based on two filtering conditions. You should rather filter them separately and concat the arrays.

```
let examBank = this.props.toggleExamBankState.tests.filter((tests: ITest) =>
        tests.companyPN.includes("25000"))
        .concat(
        this.props.toggleExamBankState.question.filter((questions: IQuestion) =>
          questions.companyPN.includes("250001)));
```

Comment: It does not allow me to use `.concat`. I get `Property 'concat' does not exist on type 'boolean'`

Comment: check the brackets

Comment: maybe you put .concat without closing the filter bracket after .includes()